# remove rich text category from lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I use the lightning:recordEditForm and further in the form lightning:inputField. One of the fields is a rich text field.
Now I want to remove some of the categories, like it is possible in lightning:inputRichText.

The only approach I could think of was to find the < ul> with the [aria-label='Align text'] attribute and delete it, but as it seems this isn't possible from the components javascript.

How would i do that without changing to a lightning:inputRichText?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please update your question with more details like what you want more specifics.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "RTF" (a file format Salesforce doesn't use) to "rich text". It sounds like you have a rich text field in your object that's being shown via a `<lightning:inputField>`, and you want to change how the rich text editing interface is being displayed. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<lightning:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) component doesn't support any tailoring of the types of formatting that can be applied to underlying Rich Text fields, as [`<lightning:inputRichText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputRichText/documentation) does.

Because of Locker Service, you won't be able to reach into the component's elements to make any changes to its displayed UI. You'll need to use the component that supports these options.